# Speed up and reverse a video with a single command?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I know with FFMPEG you can use this command to reverse a video.

```
ffmpeg -i [input] -vf reverse -af areverse [output]
```

Now, the thing is I found somewhere that you can use this command to speed up the video.

```
ffmpeg -i [input] -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=2.0*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" [output]
```

So, I tried this command to speed up and reverse the video, but it didn't work since complex filters can't be used together with -vf or -af.

```
ffmpeg -i [input] -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=2.0*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vf reverse -af areverse [output]
```

What command do I need to use to get FFmpeg to speed up and reverse the video, without decompiling it? I'm using the latest version of FFmpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it can be shorter, if you don't need to decrease the speed, so keeping the current video speed:

```
ffmpeg -i [input path] -vf reverse -af areverse [dest path]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i [input] -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=2.0*PTS,reverse[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5,areverse[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" [output]
```